# Roll-out table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to replicate this kind of effect:
http://results.glasgow2014.com/PDIS/PDIS_WL.html

As you click on the individual tables, they roll-out and show content.

I think it's a pretty basic and common thing.

I tried to use the "show more/ click to expand" style jQuery, but that only works for solid text. I wasn't able to implement that into the table structure.

What's the best to go about this?

Comment: Please show what you tried (jQuery) with your desired HTML markup (some basic CSS would not hurt)

Comment: Basically the table they show is wrapped inside a `<div>` with CSS `display:none;`. The button is located inside another table above that DIV. On that element click you simply target the `.next("div")` and do a `slideToggle()`. That's it.

Comment: thank you. I managed to figure it out. Was much easier than I thought. My lack of knowledge of JS is probably to blame here..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan one more thing regarding your technique. How do I target the divs 'dynamically'? When I have more tables (with the same div classes) and I click one, they all roll out (which I obviously don't want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to use jQuery UI [`Accordion`](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

> Displays collapsible content panels for presenting information in a
>   limited amount of space.

Here is one of the examples, how you can use it:

```js
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $this.parent().next();

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
      allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
      $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
    }

    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion {
  margin: 50px;
}
.accordion dt,
.accordion dd {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.accordion dt:last-of-type,
.accordion dd:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.accordion dt a,
.accordion dd a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion dd {
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.accordion dd:last-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="accordion">

  <dt><a href="">Panel 1</a></dt>
  <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</dd>

  <dt><a href="">Panel 2</a></dt>
  <dd>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</dd>

  <dt><a href="">Panel 3</a></dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo,
    eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: oh, this is exactly what I was thinking about initially. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries and good luck! :)